# Different countdown for each carousel element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

I am trying to accomplish what seems to be a simple and straight forward procedure.
I have a `<Carousel>` and I want each element in it to have a countdown based on an expiring date coming from my Firestore DB. The issue is that I cannot `setState` otherwise all of my elements are going to have the same countdown.

What is the best approach to have each element have its own countdown?

Here are is some code examples.

```
export default function whosRightRespond({navigation}){

let timer;
const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0)
const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(0)
const [hours, setHours] = useState(0)
const [days, setDays] = useState(0)


function timeBetweenDates(item) {
    let now = new Date(),
        expireDate = item.surveyExpirationDate.toDate()

    let difference = expireDate.getTime() - now.getTime();

    if (difference <= 0) {
        // Timer done
        clearInterval(timer);
    } else {

        let secs = Math.floor(difference / 1000);
        let mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
        let hrs = Math.floor(mins / 60);
        let dys = Math.floor(hrs / 24);

        hrs %= 24;
        mins %= 60;
        secs %= 60;

        setSeconds(secs)
        setMinutes(mins)
        setHours(hrs)
        setDays(dys)
    }
}

function renderSurveys({item}){

    timer = setInterval(function () {
        timeBetweenDates(item);
    }, 1000);

    return(
        <Container>  
              <Text>{days}, {hours}, {minutes}, {seconds}</Text>    
        </Container>
    )
}

return(
        <Carousel
            sliderWidth={width}
            itemWidth={width}
            inactiveSlideScale={1}
            slideStyle={{ width }}
            renderItem={renderSurveys}
            data={surveys}>
        </Carousel>

)
}
```

The `timeBetweenDates()` function works great.
I just need to have a better architecture to allow for multiple countdowns without messing with each other. I don't think state will work, but I am not entirely sure what to do at this point.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is another approach I tried today, but this time nothing renders.
Note the changes only in the `timeBetweenDates()` function and in the `<Text>` render

```
function timeBetweenDates(item) {

    let secs =0;
    let mins= 0;
    let hrs =0;
    let dys=0;
    timer = setInterval(function () {

        let now = new Date(),
            expireDate = item.surveyExpirationDate.toDate();

        let difference = expireDate.getTime() - now.getTime();

        if (difference <= 0) {
            console.log('done');
            // Timer done
            clearInterval(timer);
        } else {
            console.log('go');
            if(render){
                setRender(false)

            }else{
                setRender(true)

            }
            secs = Math.floor(difference / 1000);
            mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
            hrs = Math.floor(mins / 60);
            dys = Math.floor(hrs / 24);

            hrs %= 24;
            mins %= 60;
            secs %= 60;

        }
    }, 1000);
    return dys + ' days ' + hrs + ' hours ' + mins + ' mins ' + secs + ' secs';
}

function renderSurveys({item}){
    return(
        <Container>  
                <Text>Expiring in: {timeBetweenDates(item)}</Text>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to accomplish this is actually quite simple. I ended up creating a Countdown component. I then use that component in my `renderSurveys()`function. The Countdown component has all the logic described above (with `state`). That way each component is unique to its own counter and state. Let me know if you need more clarification.